# Exceptions not being logged to console.

Tags: spring-mvc, logging

I am relatively new to Spring MVC framework and it's logging concepts. When I run an application and an exception occurs(For Ex: NullPointerException), the stack trace is being displayed on the browser itself. the console just says there is an exception.

My problem is that most of the stack trace is not visible on the browser because the layout does not have enough width. Is there a way to make the stack trace print in the console? Thanks.

Here is my log4j.xml in case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <!-- Application Loggers -->
    <logger name="com.npc">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.hibernate">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: @skaffman Please help me if you can!

Answer (score 0):

Try specify

`<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n`**%ex**`" />`